# How to link wsock32 library through g++?

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I'm using minGW on windows, trying to compile a c++ program. I've used sockets in there, so I'm trying to link (not include... I've already included winsock.h) the wsock32 library. I know that the -L switch is for linking but none of the following commands work:

```
g++ C:\program.cpp -Lwsock32.lib
g++ C:\program.cpp -LC:\windows\system32\wsock32.dll
g++ C:\program.cpp -lC:\windows\system32\wsock32.dll
g++ C:\program.cpp -LC:\windows\system32\wsock32.lib
```

what should I do??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-L` option is for setting the directory where the linker should look for libraries/dlls.

The `-l` option is for naming the libraries/dlls you want to link with.

That would mean

```
g++ C:\Program.cpp -LC:\Windows\System32 -lwsock32
```

should be the command to compile your program from your regular windows command prompt.

I suspect your compiler may look in system32 automatically, so you may want to just try to skip the `-L` option.

Comment: Incidentally, you probably want -lws2_32

Comment: Although, if I actually use the -L switch, it doesn't work! Instead, I face a million weird errors!

Comment: @Joachim, Why not just use `-lc:\windows\system32\wsock32`?

Answer (score 8):

As @Joshua commented, you probably want `ws2_32.dll`.

The GNU Compiler Collection uses ranlib [archives](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) (A files) rather than Visual Studio LIB files.

The w32headers project provides `gcc`- and `g++`-compatible headers and archives for most standard Windows DLLs, including `ws2_32.dll`. The name of the archive is usually the name of the DLL minus the `.dll` extension, prefixed with `lib` and suffixed with `.a` (following the *nix archive naming convention). Thus, the symbols for `ws2_32.dll` are in `libws2_32.a`, which can be linked with using `‑lws2_32`.

By default, the w32headers archives are in the GNU `ld` library path, so to be able to link with standard Windows DLLs, there is no need to add library directories with an `‑L` option. In your case, the only option that you need is `‑lws2_32`:

```
g++ C:\Program.cpp -lws2_32
```

Assuming that compilation and linking succeed, the output will be `a.exe` in the current directory. You can override the name of the output binary with the `‑o` option.

**NOTE:** I used non-breaking hyphens in my answer. If you copy & paste the command line options, be sure to replace all hyphen-looking characters with regular hyphens.

Comment: @DarrenSadr, Why would you use non-breaking hyphens for?