# winsock2 undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2

I'm trying to make a simple socket server, but i don't what i'm doing wrong,
here is my code:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i take it from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738566(v=vs.85).aspx)

and the compiler output:

```
C:\Users\joseh\Documents\proyectos\prueba2\main.o   main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
C:\Users\joseh\Documents\proyectos\prueba2\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
26      C:\Users\joseh\Documents\proyectos\prueba2\Makefile.win recipe for target 'Project2.exe' failed
```

if you are wondering, i'm using Dev-c++

Sorry if is a basic question, but i'm not much familiar with c++

Comment: Which compiler? Because with Visual Studio, I literally just ran `cl.exe main.cpp` with your code and it compiled fine.

Comment: i'm using g++ compiler

Comment: this is x64 code ?

Comment: Approach any `#pragma` with caution. `#pragma` means implementation specific extension. Make certain your C++ compiler supports the pragma, because if it doesn't, the compiler is allowed to ignore the instruction and not tell you.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8993324/886887